# Methods for getting the most accurate location

Tags: android, android-location

In my app I have a location listener which logs out the location accuracy and puts a marker on a map where I am, however the accuracy is always around the 900 mark, and my location is between 0.2 and 0.5 miles off where I actually am. If I load up Google Maps it gets my location within a few meters.

What method's are there for ensuring an accurate location? I have these permissions in my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And here's my listener

```
LocationListener searchUsingLocation = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                    Log.d("FUApp", "Location changed: "+accuracy);
                    List<JSONObject> centres = sortVenuesByNearest(location);
                    try {
                        populateList(centres);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    setRefreshActionButtonState(false, R.id.search_using_location);

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            };
            Log.d("FUApp", "Starting request");
            locationService.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 50, 5, searchUsingLocation);
```

EDIT: Also my phone settings, Access location on, GPS Satelites is on and Wi-Fi & mobile network locations is on too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android tries to mask the reality of the hardware from us, but in practice there are only two location providers: GPS and network. GPS location is slow and not all devices have it, but it is accurate. Network location is faster and is supported by almost all devices, but it is less accurate.

If you know which provider you want, you are better off specifying it explicitly. It your app can work with either provider, you may want to ask the user to choose which he wants to use. Do not rely on what Android tells you, because most cheap devices are horribly provisioned, and may lie to you.

Comment: In my app the location isn't that important, I'd just like it to be as accurate as possible, so would I good method for me be something like ask specifically get Network location first, and then if possible after get GPS location?

Comment: In that case you should only use the GPS provider. Bear in mind though that some devices will not have GPS. So if you want them to be able to use your app, you may want to include an option to use the network provider instead. As I said earlier, some devices are so badly provisioned that they will say that they have a GPS receiver even when they do not. I have such a device myself.

Comment: Okay, I'll implement that method. Thanks :). Just out of curiosity what device do you have that does that?

Answer (score 4):

You are only listening `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`. If you want more accuracy you must listen other providers, but wait a minute:)

Google improved its map and location management with fused location provider. https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

With fused location; you do not need to query best location provider. If you want to get high accuracy you only set it to the location request.

```
setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
```

Comment: This looks interesting. For continuous monitoring of the current location, it may well be the way to go.

Comment: The second link (kpbird) is dead and just re-directs as a phishing link @Devrim please update

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue before few days ago.I have changed the `setPriority()` to `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`. And Its give me accurate location up to 10 Meters.

**Instead of this line**  `mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);`

**Add this line**
`mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);`

> My suggestion is to use `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`.