# Android Location Services Not Updating requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a simple class `GPSListener` which gets the GPS coordinates:

```
public class GPSListener implements LocationListener {  

public static double latitude;  
public static double longitude;  

@Override  
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)  
{  
    loc.getLatitude();  
    loc.getLongitude();  
    latitude = loc.getLatitude();  
    longitude = loc.getLongitude(); 
    Log.d("GPSLISTENER ", "lat: "+latitude+"  long:"+longitude);
} ...
```

Then trying to make use of this class in my activity, I simply invoke the class in my `onCreate()` function in my activity:

```
LocationManager mlocManager =   (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new GPSListener();

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = mlocManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, mlocListener);

    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

    if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {  
            lat = GPSListener.latitude;
            lon = GPSListener.longitude;
            Log.d("GPS", "lat: "+lat+"  long:"+lon);
    } else {  
           // TODO: GPS not enabled
            Log.d("GPSERROR", "GPS not enabled");
    }
```

But whenever I run the application, `lat` and `lon` in my activity are always zero. I'm not quite sure how to get around this issue.

When logging:

```
Log.d("GPSLISTENER ", "lat: "+latitude+"  long:"+longitude);
```

It returns the correct latitude and longitude, it just takes a second or two after the activity starts.

```
Log.d("GPSSUCCESS", "lat: "+lat+"  long:"+lon);
```

Just returns 0.0 for both. I was under the impression that `.requestLocationUpdates` would pass the value to `lat` and `lon` before the if statement is executed. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you add the permission (android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) in manifest file for location?

Comment: if you are testing on emulator you need to pass the coordinates to it or if you are on your device please restart the device and check.

Comment: @Shrikant I am testing on my device. It is able to get the GPS coordinates in GPSListener, as I stated, so I don't think it is a communication error. I think it is more likely to be a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using public static field for latitude, longitude.

Please change it to non static and using setter, getter with instant object:

```
lat = mlocListener.getLatitude();
lon = mlocListener.getLongitude();
```

Comment: You can replace:
 mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

by:
Location loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Answer (score 1):

Google updated its location handling logic. It is now easier to listen location updates with fused location provider. You can implement your location listener in 5 min. Take a look.
[Methods for getting the most accurate location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869451/methods-for-getting-the-most-accurate-location/18869939#18869939)

You are listening only gps provider and it is not ready(on waiting for location status) yet and then it does not return any location. Just take a look at fused location provider and write your location listener again.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick()
                {
                    try
                        {
                            Location myLocation = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();
                            onLocationChanged(myLocation);

                        }
                    catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.getStackTraceString(e);
                        }

                    return false;
                }
        });
```

user this Handler to get Location

```
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();


   private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run()
        {
            try
                {

                    Location myLocation = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();
                    secndLocationListener.onLocationChanged(myLocation);
                }
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.getStackTraceString(e);
                }

        }
};
```

to run this

```
   customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread , 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

LocationManager uses the last known location from the cache. The cache is updated when you load google maps. Try this out, go out in the open and check your location. Move to a different location about 200m and check your location again. It will be same as the old one. Now, load google maps, you will notice that you application magically now has the new location.

You need to programmatically kick that cache to the latest location. The only way to do that is

```
YOUR_APPLICATION_CONTEXT.getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    }
});
```